# Delete button in UI-grid angular not render in row

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Hi any help will be appreciable.
I want to add a delete button in angular UI-grid but success is so far. my code is like as :

View have below line of code:

```
<div id="grdAreaDetails" external-scopes="$scope" 
    ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" 
    ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-cellnav ui-grid-selection >
</div>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'code' },
    { name: 'name' },
    { name: 'notes' },
    { name: 'description' },
    { name: 'status' },
    { name: 'Action', 
     cellEditableCondition: false, 
     cellTemplate: '<button > Report</button>' 
    }
];

var g= [{ code: 'AREA1', name: 'Dalip', notes: 'Hello World', description: 1, status: 'Active' }];

$scope.gridOptions = {

    enableSorting: true,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    enablePaging: true,
    showFooter: true,
            data:g,
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, $scope.UpdateArea);
    }
};
```

but gridview on UI display only five column instead of action button.

please suggest........

Comment: I can see the action button in the plunker I created from your code snippet http://plnkr.co/edit/VeBeSHOrob40tRzGIk0Q?p=preview

Comment: Right, but on mine development machine same code not working.what may be the possible causes..........  please suggest..stuck from 2 days

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: No error on consol. only image not found like error are there...

Comment: I would remove image errors first to make sure it does not interfere results

Comment: But when if i set value in data for button column than column is visible with simple text. like as below

var g= [{ code: 'AREA1', name: 'Dalip', notes: 'Hello World', description: 1, status: 'Active' ,Action:'hello'}];